# get firestore id of component in displaying through map in React.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am developing a web app using ReactJs and firebase(firestore). On a page, I am fetching all documents from 'submissions' collection and mapping over them to display the Submission component. There is a field 'vote' in document which i want to manipulate by clicking on 'upvote' button present on submission card.

Competitions page where I am fetching the data and passing it through props in Submission Component. (Competition.js)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { SRLWrapper } from "simple-react-lightbox";
import Card from '../../components/Competition-info/Card'; 
import Footer from '../../components/Footer/Footer';
import Nav from '../../components/Nav-new/Nav'
import Submissions from '../../components/Submissions/Submissions';
import Leaderboard from '../../components/Leaderboard/Leaderboard'; 
import './competition.css';
import firebase from '../../firebase'

const db = firebase.firestore();

const Competition = (props) => {
const options = {
    buttons: {
        showAutoplayButton: false,
        showDownloadButton: false
    }
};

const [mySubs, setMySubs] = useState([])
const [passSubs, setPassSubs] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('submissions').where('competition_id', '==', props.match.params.id).get()
    .then((querySnap) => {
        querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
            setMySubs(prevState => [...prevState, doc.data()]);
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    })
},[])
console.log('mysubs: ', mySubs);
return (
    <div className='competition-pg'>
        <Nav />
        <div className='competition-content'>
            <div className='cover-img'>
                <div className='cover-dp'></div>
            </div>
            <Card id={props.match.params.id} />
            <section className='section-submission'>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/competition/participant" component={Leaderboard} />
                </Switch>
                <Leaderboard id={props.match.params.id} />
                <h2 className='submission-title'>Submissions</h2>
                <SRLWrapper options={options}>
                    <div className='submissions'>
                        {
                            mySubs && mySubs.map(submission => {
                                return(
                                    <Submissions submission={submission} key={submission.id} />
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </SRLWrapper>
            </section>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </div>
)
}


export default Competition
```

Submission.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './submissions.css'
import { AiFillLike } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { FaShareAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';


const Submissions = (props) => {

return (
    <div className={`submission ${"active"?"selected":""}`} >
        <div className='sub-head'>
            <p>{props.submission.user_name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='sub-img-container'>
         <img alt='' src={props.submission.photo_link} className='wrapper-img' />
        </div>
        <div className='vote-container'>
            <a href={()=>false} className='btn-vote'><AiFillLike /></a>
            <a href={()=>false} className='btn-vote'><FaShareAlt /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Submissions
```

Web page:

[image: My Web page]

My database:
[image]

So, basically i want to update the vote field in the document through this 'upvote' button which is present in submission component. How do i get the id of the particular document so that i can update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use both document data and id then you should probably wrap your documents with additional info.

When you are mapping docs from `Firestore` you can replace:

```
querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
    setMySubs(prevState => [...prevState, doc.data()]);
})
```

With this code:

```
querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
    setMySubs(prevState => [
        ...prevState, 
        { 
            id: doc.id(), 
            data: doc.data(),
        },
    ]);
})
```

Don't forget to update your other code to use `.data` field.

This allows you to manipulate with both document contents and id (or any other metadata you wish).

Comment: Thanks. But how would I know which document to update when 'upvote' button is clicked, according to the submission card that is displaying that document. Can you write the code of 'upvote' button (btn-vote) in submission.js so that vote of that particular submission increases?